# Queryset with collated/merged values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have the following two models:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    movement = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

And I have the following DRF `generics.ListAPIView` where I want to be able to search/filter on `Child` objects but actually return the related `Parent` objects:

```py
class ParentSearchByChildNameView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Return a list of parents who have a child with the given name
    """
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        child_name = self.request.query_params.get('name')

        queryset = Child.objects.all()
        if child_name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__contains=child_name)

        matched_parents = Parent.objects.filter(children__in=queryset).distinct()
        return matched_parents
```

Now, this works well for me. If a `Parent` object has 3 `Child` objects which all match the given "name" `query_param`, then I only get one `Parent` object back, which is what I want:

```json
{
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "URL to parent",
            "name": "Parent #1",
        }
    ]
}
```

However, what I also want is to indicate the matched `Child` object IDs within the result. If I may illustrate in JSON what I want:

```json
{
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "URL to parent",
            "name": "Parent #1",
            "matched_child": [1, 3, 7]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this something I can do with built-in tools, without expensively and repeatedly hitting the database?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLite for local dev and Postgres for prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making use of a database-specific feature, you can work with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class ParentSearchByChildNameView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Return a list of parents who have a child with the given name
    """
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        child_name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
        return = Parent.objects.filter(
            children__name__contains=child_name
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('children', Child.objects.filter(name=child_name), to_attr='matched_children')
        ).distinct()
```

For the serializer we then can work with a [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield):

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    matched_children = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'matched_children']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), you can work with an [**`ArrayAgg`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

class ParentSearchByChildNameView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Return a list of parents who have a child with the given name
    """
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        child_name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
        return = Parent.objects.filter(
            children__name__contains=child_name
        ).annotate(matched_children=ArrayAgg('children__pk'))
```

In the serializer you thus add a `ListField` that will list the children with:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    matched_children = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.IntegerField(),
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'matched_children']
```